# How to resize a svg

Tags: html, svg

I want to reduce the size of a svg. I tried reducing the `height` and `width` attributes and that helped, but the size of the image is still too big and when I try to reduce more, it ends up being cut instead of reduced.

So, more specifically, if I have a svg like this one:

```html
<svg height="15" width="28" fill="#D0D4D9" fill-rule="evenodd">
  <path d="M12 18c-4.536 0-7.999-4.26-7.999-6 0-2.001 3.459-6 8-6 4.376 0 7.998 3.973 7.998 6 0 1.74-3.462 6-7.998 6m0-14C6.48 4 2 8.841 2 12c0 3.086 4.576 8 10 8 5.423 0 10-4.914 10-8 0-3.159-4.48-8-10-8"></path>
  <path d="M11.977 13.984c-1.103 0-2-.897-2-2s.897-2 2-2c1.104 0 2 .897 2 2s-.896 2-2 2m0-6c-2.206 0-4 1.794-4 4s1.794 4 4 4c2.207 0 4-1.794 4-4s-1.793-4-4-4"></path>
</svg>
```

how can I resize it? Is there maybe an online page when we can do that or a general rule for this?

Comment: SVG element doesn't have any `size`, they are only made by vectors, and you can show them in any size you want. by the your SVG code can be used if you din't use a `viewbox` attribute

Comment: Use a viewBox attribute for the svg element and delete the width and the height. The svg element will take all the width available. Try `viewBox="0 0 24 24" `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SVG** elements have no actual size, they are made up of vectors to precisely be displayed in any size.
The first problem with your SVG code is to have omitted the [`viewbox` attribute.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)
You can calculate its values using the JS method: [SVGGraphicsElement.getBBox()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox).
In your case your viewBox is: `viewBox="2 4 20 16"`

Then simply change `css` values of `width` and `height`, according to the viewbox props (20 / 16).

this will be :

```js
const mySVG = document.querySelector('#my-svg');

function toggleSize()
  {
  mySVG.classList.toggle('sz200');
  }
```

```css
svg {
  width      : 100px;
  height     :  80px;
  margin     :  20px;
  background : blue;
  fill       : #D0D4D9;
  fill-rule  : evenodd;
  }
.sz200 {
  width      : 200px;
  height     : 160px;
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleSize()">toggle size: (100-80) | (200-160)</button>
  <br>
 
<svg id="my-svg" viewBox="2 4 20 16" >
  <path d="
    M 12 18 c -4.536 0-7.999-4.26-7.999-6 0-2.001 3.459-6 8-6 4.376 0 7.998 
    3.973 7.998 6 0 1.74-3.462 6-7.998 6 m 0-14 C 6.48 4 2 8.841 2 12 
    c 0 3.086 4.576 8 10 8 5.423 0 10 -4.914 10-8 0 -3.159 -4.48 -8 -10 -8" />
  <path d="
    M 11.977 13.984 c -1.103 0-2-.897-2-2 s .897-2 2-2 c 1.104 0 2 .897 2 2 
    s -.896 2-2 2 m 0-6 c -2.206 0-4 1.794-4 4 s 1.794 4 4 4 c 2.207 0 4-1.794 
    4-4 s -1.793-4-4-4" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the height from `15` to `auto`

```
<svg
    height="auto"
    width="28"
    fill="#D0D4D9"
    fill-rule="evenodd"
>
    <path
        d="M12 18c-4.536 0-7.999-4.26-7.999-6 0-2.001 3.459-6 8-6 4.376 0 7.998 3.973 7.998 6 0 1.74-3.462 6-7.998 6m0-14C6.48 4 2 8.841 2 12c0 3.086 4.576 8 10 8 5.423 0 10-4.914 10-8 0-3.159-4.48-8-10-8"
    ></path>
    <path
        d="M11.977 13.984c-1.103 0-2-.897-2-2s.897-2 2-2c1.104 0 2 .897 2 2s-.896 2-2 2m0-6c-2.206 0-4 1.794-4 4s1.794 4 4 4c2.207 0 4-1.794 4-4s-1.793-4-4-4"
    ></path>
</svg>
```